# Android Emulator: invalid command-line parameter

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I launch my emulator, I get the following error:

**invalid command-line parameter: Android Development\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe.**

**Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information**

But my emulator is mark as "**A valid Android Virtual Device**".

How should I solve this error?

---

**UPDATE:**

i just solved this problem.

See answer below.

Comment: windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe. may be problem is here in slash

Comment: try this windows\tools\emulator-arm.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake that I named my folder "**Android Development**" where I have put my sdk. I realized that *having a path that have an empty space between letters or words*, like in my case "**Android Development**" have caused this error.

I just transferred my android sdk to another folder and make sure that i named it properly(without blank space), for example "**Android_Development**".

Comment: You shouldn't take the blame for giving a folder a name with a space in it! We are in the 21st century and programmers should be aware by now, that there are OSes out there that allow such names! But to some brains that truth hasn't trickled through, yet...

Answer (score 1):

check your sdk path. Make sure the path should not have an empty space like ..../my Sdk/sdk-windos/

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the blank space** from your SDK path by renaming the path(if blank space is there)

or give proper command

```
emulator -avd "avdname"
```

note: AVD must exist with name "avdname"

Answer (score 0):

There is one more aspect to this problem. If RAM size is more than the AVD can get from system, the same error is thrown.